# Triple Integration in R

Tags: r

I'm using kernel utilization distributions to describe bird territories and also to estimate overlap between multiple territories. There are several ways to calculate overlap and one of the published methods is called a UDOI. The equation is 
$$UDOI = V1,2 \iiint UD1 (x,y,z) \times UD2 (x,y,z) dxdydz$$

where `UD1` is the utilization distribution in $3$ spatial dimensions ($x,y,z$) of bird 1 and `UD2` is the same for bird 2. I already know how to calculate the UDs, but trying to figure out how to carry out the rest of the formula in `R`.

After spending 30 minutes with a math Prof. I think that A1,2 should be changed to V1,2 and represents the volume of space overlapped by both birds. Also, if her understanding was correct dxdydz is simply the volume of each voxel (3D pixel). I've added some code to help in figuring these things out (see below).

```
a <- read.csv("W_OA_ASY_M_LII_2012.csv")
b <- read.csv("WG_A_F_LII_2012.csv")

Ha <- Hpi(a) 
Hb <- Hpi(b) 

c <- rbind(a, b)

minX <- min(c$X) - 25  #$
minY <- min(c$Y) - 25 
minZ <- 0  

maxX <- max(c$X) + 25  #$
maxY <- max(c$Y) + 25  #$
maxZ <- max(c$Z) + 5 

fhata <- kde(x=a, H=Ha, binned=FALSE, xmin=c(minX,minY,minZ), xmax=c(maxX,maxY,maxZ)) 
fhatb <- kde(x=b, H=Hb, binned=FALSE, xmin=c(minX,minY,minZ), xmax=c(maxX,maxY,maxZ))
```

Everything above produces data provided in the link in the comments where fhata=UD1 and fhatb=UD2

```
#determines volume of each territory
cta<-contourLevels(UD1, cont=100, approx=FALSE)
ctb<-countourLevels(UD2, cont=100, approx=FALSE)

#Overlap = Volume of overlap between 2 territories
fhat.overlap<-UD1
fhat.overlap$estimate<-UD1$estimate>cta & UD2$estimate>ctb
Overlap<-countourSizes(fhat.overlap, abs.cont=0.5)

#Determines length, width, and height of total area assessed and divides by grid size (51)
#VoxelSize = volume of each voxel
X<-maxX-minX
Y<-maxY-minY
Z<-maxZ-minZ
VoxelSize<-(X/51)*(Y/51)*(Z/51)
```

So now the question is how to put this all together. Does this estimate UDOI in a quick and dirty way? This is where my lack of math is hurting me....

```
Overlap*sum(UD1*UD2*VoxelSize)
```

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/ will help you better i believe.

Comment: Produce some sample data.

Comment: more details (what form is the compated UD in?), and check out the `cubature` package.

Comment: @BhrugeshPatel is right, but please don't cross-post.  Rather it will be migrated soon if moderators determine migration is the right course of action.

Comment: @DWin         What is the best way to do this? I can produce the R code and a small dataset. Does that work?

Comment: If you are communicating with R users, the `dput` function allows you to present data objects so they can be transferred accurately.

Comment: @BenBolker     Forgive my ignorance, but what exactly do you mean? After using "ks" to produce the UD's everything is saved in an object (class "kde"). Looks like a very large matrix with density values for the thousands of points density is estimated at.

Comment: @DWin          Okay - here is a link to 2 different UD's. The relevant data is in "estimate" I believe.    https://docs.google.com/folder/d/0BxgZ4ul4g0BHSzBKWFdNRm1XUWc/edit

Comment: Those are not created with equal grid sizes but rather withtwo different Hpi() objects having some sort of adaptive? bandwidths. I guess you should replace those with a file created by:  `save(UD1, UD2, file="UD1_2.Rdata")`.

Comment: @DWin          The Hpi is a plug in bandwidth estimator that seems to be the one recommended most these days. a and b are simply the text files with the location data.   I'm confused as to what you want. Do you just want me to re-save those files using the code you provided or do something different and then save those files?  Also, when I re-import those files I sent you and do summary and dim on both it is showing that estimate is 132,651 long and the dimensions are 51, 51, 51 in both cases.

Comment: There are two different `UD1` and two different `UD2` objects on your download site -- that might be a source of confusion.  Can you delete one set?

Comment: @BenBolker     Just deleted, but they should be the same.

Comment: Maybe Ben can get them loaded. I tried and they 'broke' my session (repeatedly). That's why I asked for a `save`-ed version and I will resume my efforts if one is made available. @user1911070: do you NOW see why code is needed? This _should_ have been conducted on SO, but by making it a vague question people mistakenly jumped to the conclusion that you needed theoretical advice.

Comment: @DWin          Here you go.... https://docs.google.com/open?id=0BxgZ4ul4g0BHMmtNUks5LVl1Z0k. Lesson learned. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3):

Along the lines of DWin answer, but taking into account the grid size...

```
> sum(UD1$estimate)
[1] 0.6217264
> sum(UD2$estimate)
[1] 0.622008
```

Is that ok? Let's look at the grid.

```
> lapply( UD1$eval.points, function(x) head(diff(x)))
[[1]]
[1] 2.42362 2.42362 2.42362 2.42362 2.42362 2.42362

[[2]]
[1] 2.365521 2.365521 2.365521 2.365521 2.365521 2.365521

[[3]]
[1] 0.28 0.28 0.28 0.28 0.28 0.28
```

So the result should be

```
> 1/(2.42362*2.365521*0.28)
[1] 0.6229463
```

This looks good to me. Your integral can be roughly evaluated by

```
> sum(UD2$estimate*UD1$estimate)/0.622
[1] 2.189203e-05
```

This is quick an (very) dirty. You should not rely on this result but try this again with much more points in the grid (say, a 200 × 200 × 200 grid at least).

Or you should find a way to evaluate the density at a point of the space, and go for a Monte Carlo integration. I tried this, using the formula displayed in `kde` vignette (with covariance matrix `UD1$H` and `UD2$H`), but I failed to obtain the same values as in the `estimate` component. **If someone knows how to do that, I’ll be interested.** The `kde` package seems very nice, but oriented towards graphic visualization. There's nothing to evaluate the kernel densities at a given point, for example.

**Post Scriptum**

Of course this quantity is very small: if the two distributions were the same, we would obtain

```
> sum(UD1$estimate*UD1$estimate)/0.622
[1] 9.573283e-05
> sum(UD2$estimate*UD2$estimate)/0.622
[1] 5.473942e-05
```

You have to use some reference term, dividing your `2.2e-5` by either one of the above quantities, or by the bigger one, or by the mean of the two... I don’t know. The volume of space in which they overlap is not a well defined notion. Note that the “voxel size” here is `1/0.6229463`.

Finally, when you edit a question, please write a Post Scriptum rather than transforming it in an other question: that makes the answers given hard to understand, or even that makes them look stupid... In the present case you are basically asking if someone can confirm that my answer is correct, a single line would have been sufficient... I can’t confirm that...

Comment: The solution you provided seems to give a very small number. The index varies from 0 (no overlap) to 1 (high overlap) and the two birds that were provided in the datasets overlap by about 31% based on volume alone. It could be that they really don't share this space much using the new measure, but from looking at the plots this seems counter intuitive.

Comment: Also, I changed the grid size to 200 and the volume overlap that I normally calculate changes by only about .2%. It may affect this new measure more, but not sure....

Comment: @user1911070 I edited my answer to address this point.

Answer (score 2):

If the items you put up on the web are derived using `ks::kde` then the 'estimate' component is a 3D matrix with 51 points in each dimension. Try doing this:

```
sum( UD1$estimate )   # should be close to 1.000 if it is a density object
```

If that test is successful, then you should not need anything fancy and this should be all you need:

```
UDOI <- sum( UD1$estimate * UD2$estimate )
```

Integration is just a glorified form of addition, and if the grid dimensions were set up as being the same, you should be able to do "numerical integration" by simply adding up the `pmin` function result over the entire volume.

Now that we know that the claim that these are on the same grid is highly suspect we start the process of debugging/clarification.re-examining assumptions ....

See what this returns:

```
identical( prod(dim( UD1$estimate)), length(UD1$estimate) )
```

Comment: Okay I tried sum(UD1$estimate) and I did use kde. I tried it for two different UD's and the sum is about 0.62 for both. I used the same grid dimensions here. If I don't do that and let kde choose the default grid dimensions then one of them = 1.14 and the other = 0.72. Also I tried the UDOI you suggested and get 1.35 x 10^-5. These two territories overlap quite a bit so the result should be much bigger.

Comment: It's taking a really long time to import those objects, but I think I have a strategy that will bear fruit in a few more minutes. I'm up to 120,000 datapoints out of 132,651 on the first one.

Comment: Now that I have the estimated densities I find that the dimensions are not the same. The first one had 151658 (53*53*54 ???) items, while the second one had 159623 (53 x 54 x 55, perhaps?)  So by changing the gridsize which defaults to c(51,51,51) I think you have prevented a proper estimate. I say again  .... you need to post your code!

Comment: Okay, I get FALSE

Comment: The sum shouldn't be close to 1 !! There's a grid size to take into account. `x <- dnorm(seq(-10,10, length=100)); sum(x);` produces `4.95`.

Comment: Point taken. Sum density*delta-x should be 1, though. Still need to get the two density matrices on the same grid and then use the grid size to normalize the calculations.